# clickable (gui) Bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting, gui, menu

Was just finishing some script containing a choice menu and was wondering if there's a tool out there that could be called by a script, provides a 1-click-choice-menu and returns the result back to the script.

Impossible that such doesn't exist, but... ever tried to google "bash menu click/mouse/gui/whatever"?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of tools for adding GUI interaction to your shell scripts, including:

- [dialog](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807)
- [xdialog](http://xdialog.free.fr)
- [zenity](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/Zenity)

And there are undoubtedly others.

Comment: awsome, you're my hero of the day. Thank you =)

Comment: @muab: Do not forget to mark the answer that helped you as "correct". It helps to track down answered questions.

Comment: The "original" would probably be [`ipick`](http://bima.astro.umd.edu/nemo/man_html/ipick.l.html).

Answer (score 3):

I would use `zenity` with command substitution mechanism:

```
$ shell=$(zenity --list --text "What's your favorite shell?" --title "My title" --column="shells" "bash" "csh" "ksh" "zsh")
$ echo "$shell"
zsh
```

Comment: great, exactly(!) the dialog I needed ^^ (except for the strings of course ,p). Thx